# How can I join quizzes on different python files together

Tags: python, kivy

I am using kivy. I built quizzes on separate python files and I also built a main python file on which I want to put the quizzes in.

The application should, at the end, be able to open each quiz as you press the button holding the quiz name.

I have been trying for almost 2 weeks now and I searched all over the internet but can’t seem to find an answer so I really appreciate any help.

This is what I have in the class where I want the first quiz to be on the main python file:

```
from app import Question

class NineteenWindow(Screen):

    pass
```

App is the name of the file that 
has the quiz and Question is the quiz class.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is:

When you import your own python file, you can access functions and variables like normal. Assuming you have `app` , and functions inside it, you could call it via `app.show_first_quiz()` or whatever you named it. If I remember correctly, if you have code outside if a function call, in the global scope, that code will be executed when you import the module. If you have `say_hi.py` that prints (hello)`outside of a function, it will print hello in any projevt where you`import say_hi` but if it is in a function call, it will only print hello when you call the function it's encapsulated in.